# Find the error approximation for the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: numerical-methods

> **Problem**
>   Let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$, find the Taylor polynomial $P_n(x)$ about $x_0 = 0$. Find a value of $n$ such that the approximation is within $10^{-6}$ on $[0, 0.5]$.

To find $P_n(x)$ is straightforward, 
$$f^{(1)}(x) = \dfrac{-1}{(1 - x)^2}$$
            $$f^{(2)}(x) = \dfrac{2}{(1 - x)^3}$$
            $$f^{(3)}(x) = \dfrac{-6}{(1 - x)^4}$$
            $$f^{(4)}(x) = \dfrac{24}{(1 - x)^5}$$
            $$f^{(5)}(x) = \dfrac{-120}{(1 - x)^6}$$
$$\ldots$$

$$f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n \dfrac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$
At $x_0 = 0$, the Taylor polynomial is:

$$P_n(x) = \dfrac{f(0)}{0!} + \dfrac{f^{(1)}(0)}{1!}x + \dfrac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!}x^2 + \ldots + \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
$$= 1 - x + \dfrac{2}{2!}x^2 + \dfrac{-6}{3!}x^3 + \ldots + (-1)^n\dfrac{n!}{n!}x^n$$
$$= 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \ldots + (-1)^nx^n$$

However, I realize this Taylor polynomial is weird somehow, for example if I plug in $x = 0.5$ then
$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-0.5} = 2$$
while approximate with the Taylor polynomial, $n$ has to be extremely large. I don't even know how large it could be to get close to $10^{-6}$.
On the other hand, to find the error approximation I use the formula 
$$R_n(x) = \dfrac{f^{(n + 1)}(\xi(x))}{(n + 1)!} \cdot x^{n + 1} $$
$$= (-1)^{n + 1} \cdot \dfrac{(n + 1)!}{(1 - \xi(x))^{n + 2}} \cdot \dfrac{x^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!}$$
$$= (-1)^{n + 1} \dfrac{x^{n + 1}}{(1 - \xi(x))^{n + 2}}$$
where $x \in [0, 0.5] \implies \xi(x) \in [0, 0.5]$. Then to maximize $R_n(x)$, I picked $x = 0.5$ and $\xi(x) = 0.5$ which yields:
$$R_n(x) = (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{0.5^{n+1}}{(1-0.5)^{n+2}} = (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{0.5^n}$$

Apparently, this doesn't make any sense because $R_n$ is getting bigger and bigger as $n$ increase. And the solution in the textbook is $n = 19$. So there must be something wrong along the way, but I couldn't find where. I wonder if anyone could give me a hint to this problem. I'm new to Numerical Analysis and my lecture notes doesn't help at all. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You have a sign wrong - there is both a negative power and a $-x$ - check your derivative.

Comment: It's just the geometric series formula, yo. You can even use it to deduce $$f(x)-P_n(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\le\frac{1}{2^n}\text{ on }[0,1/2].$$ (Though maybe that's a cheap solution if some homework problem wants a more Taylor-flavored analysis.)

Comment: @Mark Bennet: Thank you. Did you mean the formula of $f^{(n)}$ is wrong? I've been looking at this problem for hours, I really couldn't see it well.

Comment: @anon: Thanks for the alternative approach, however I've just learned Taylor method, so I really want to focus on understanding it.

Comment: @chan: The derivative of $(1-x)^{-n}$ is $(-1)(-n)(1-x)^{-(n+1)}$

Comment: @Mark Bennet: I found my error now! I can't believe I forgot how to take derivative, what a shame!

Comment: There is an error in the last displayed formula in addition to the sign error. The rightmost entry there should be $\frac{1}{0.5}$.  That unfortunately doesn't help much!

Comment: The Lagrange form of the remainder is not directly useful here, unless we get a better than most pessimistic estimate of $\xi$.  The problem, as quoted, does not appear to specify that the Lagrange form of the remainder be used. Thus the approach of @anon seems eminently sensible in this case.

Comment: @Andre' Nicolas: Thank you. I'm exactly having the problem you have mentioned. Seem like I can't apply the $R_n(n)$ directly in this case.

Comment: I am not absolutely whether anon meant use formula for sum of infinite GP to find the "tail." It is theoretically a little better to use the fact that sum of the finite GP $1+x+\cdots +x^n$ (that is, the Taylor polynomial) is $(1-x^{n+1})/(1-x)$. Subtract this from $1/(1-x)$, then make the obvious estimate. By the way, at $x=0.5$ this is first $<10^{-6}$ if $n=20$.  Odd.